# PHP - open PDF "about:blank" page

Tags: php, pdf

When a PDF report is opened an  "untitled about:blank" page is also opened under all browsers.  Is there a way to program not to open about:blank page?

```
**sc_lookup(rsd, $check_sql);
$statement_pdf = {rsd[0][0]};
$pdf_data = base64_encode($statement_pdf);
$data = base64_decode($pdf_data);
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=statement.pdf');
echo $data;**
```

[image]

Comment: The PDF does open/download.  The PDF is stored as a blob in a table.   The development tool is Scriptcase.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your last comment

Answer (score 0):

I don't see is how your script is being invoked... That is, by clicking a link or mid another request.

#### Assuming your `$data` contains a valid PDF, you could check that the following is done:

To "force-download" on clicked links, you pretty much have it, provided your link does not target a new tab/window.

Just make sure you have the correct headers in you php response, and that your anchor tag attributes do not have  `target="_blank"` as that will guarantee the behavior you are trying to avoid.

#### Alternatively, if `$data` is not a PDF, but rather some sort of string content, you may consider these points.

If you are attempting to serve string data, from your database as a PDF, you need to do more than say it's a PDF through the use of headers, you need to actually generate and serve a valid PDF document.

Perhaps you would consider using a library for your PDF generation, such as [fpdf](http://www.fpdf.org/) library. Because as it stands you would need to refactor things, so PDFs are stored in your Database, and/or generate real PDF documents, server side.

Here is a simple example of a download script...

```html
<?php 
    
    // Responds to the download request...
    if(isset($_REQUEST['action']) && $_REQUEST['action'] === 'download'){

        $data ="Some string content";

        // Generate and Output PDF

        require("./fpdf/fpdf.php");
 
          $pdf = new FPDF();
          $pdf->AddPage();
          $pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',16);
          $pdf->Cell(40,10,$data);
          $pdf->Output("D", 'statement.pdf');
          exit();
      
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Download - Sample</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="?action=download">Download</a>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Update, based on clarifications in the comments above from OP

You need to ensure you have all three of these headers set

```
     
    header("Content-length: $size ) // as returned by filesize($file), size of the file in bytes
    header("Content-type: $mimeType"); //application/pdf
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = $file"); //name of file, with file extension
```

If you don't already, you need to store the filesize in your database, when it's stored, otherwise you will need to do post processing when setting up the downloads to get that size.

#### What is the about:blank page anyways

It serves many purposes, but in this particular case it's the browsers default, "oh snap what should I display"... And is being triggered because the response did not have the right header information to let the  browser know what to do... Instead it let the response "play out" in an about:blank page.